# How to use Objects.filter() for a list in Mezzanine/Django?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am facing difficulty in querying element from database. Keyword is an field in BlogPost table which is list. 
e.g

```
keyword = ['python','java','django']
slug = "java"
blogs = BlogPost.objects.filter(keyword__contains=slug)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What exactly problem are you having and what are you trying to achieve? Your code has a syntax error: `java` must me quoted because it is a string: `"java"` or `'java'`. Another error is that you need to use exactly one `=` sign in the `filter` call: `keyword__contains=slug`.

Please, read Python and Django tutorial instead of learning by trial and error and asking trivial questions on SO. This will have much better effect than copying answers.

Comment: i made syntax error here in above question. I'll explain my question once again.
1. BlogPost is  a model  and keyword is field 
2. The data type of keyword is list
3. I want a list of blogs from blogpost which conatins keyword like java.

As i am using Mezzanine CMS , BlogPost is its inbuilt model

Comment: If you want to filter by several categories, use the code like this: `BlogPost.objects.filter(keyword__in=['java', 'python', 'django'])`. Still, you need to read Django tutorial. It is wrong way to build software by making changes without understanding underlying technology and then asking how to correct every arising error on SO.

Comment: BlogPost.objects.filter(['java', 'python', 'django']__in='java')
this is the issue . How to query ?

Comment: I've provided a correct syntax for querying Django querysets. You've rewritten it in a completely incorrect way that suggests that you're not familiar with Python syntax. It is impossible to develop applications in Python/Django without knowing Python basics. Apparently you don't even understand how parameters are passed to python functions/methods, hence I suggest that your read Python tutorial first: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html as it is impossible to learn a programming language from scratch by asking trivial questions on StackOverflow. You need to learn the basics first

Comment: Thank you for your support and efforts. I am not playing with any python syntax and its data structures. I think you are unaware of  Mezzanine kindly read this (http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/_modules/mezzanine/blog/models.html)
See the model structure for keyword

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with Django/Mezzanine and I provided you with a correct way to filter by keywords. But instead of learning Python/Django in order to understand how my answer works (or just copying it), you're still trying to create something by making random changes in the code. You don't understand basic Python syntax and data structures. Until you learn them properly, you won't be able to make anything useful. In your comment you put a Python list in place of a keyword argument name -> it indicates that you don't understand even how functions are called in Python.

Comment: I replcaed keyword with a list to just explain the scenario